# ng-deep is effecting sibling components

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular7

I ran into an issue using Angular Material Design where I need to use ng-deep in order to adjust the styling of an accordion. However, I am using an accordion elsewhere and it is grabbing the same styles. This is not desired.

Is it supposed to do that? How do I fix it?

Comment: Yes, that is the supposed behavior of ng-deep. It overrides the styles in the sibling components. The simplest way to fix that would be wrap your accordion inside a class in the parent component and provide ng-deep to the accordion inside that class. This would prevent leaking of style in the other components.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-deep` is deprecated, and support is being removed from major browsers. You can read more about it in the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

I would suggest you to remove the view encapsulation from the component instead (`None` removes style encapsulation for that component, so you can target Angular Material styles).

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-example-component',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that in order to keep the styles limited to the component, I had to encapsulate the ::ng-deep code with :host like so:

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep {
        /* ... custom styles here */
    }
}
```